# Data entry field displaying entered values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter

My application has a modal window with filters. I would like to add another kind of filter to it. I just don’t know how to implement it in React (perhaps you can help me with the code, recommend links).

The meaning is as follows: I want the filters to have a line in which the user could write some value on his own, press Enter, see the entered result (it is possible to enter several values ​​by which you can filter).

Perhaps my explanation is chaotic, in addition I will provide a screenshot with the desired result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For UI you can use or create a custom input field like this https://evergreen.segment.com/components/tag-input.

For implementation:
Now you have fields searched by user
Ex-

```js
const list =  [2,3,4,56,7,8,12,34,0,1]
const searchedItems =  [3,7,8]
const finalList= [];
function searchItems() {
   list.forEach(item => {
     searchedItems.forEach(ele => {
       if(ele===item) finalList.push(item);
   })
  });
  return finalList;
}
console.log(searchItems())
```

Finally use this array in your search item results.

Answer (score 1):

```
export function ListItem({ itemValue }) {
  return (
    <div className="item">
      <span className="itemValue">{itemValue}</span>
    </div>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  const [itemList, setListItem] = useState([]);
  const [item, setItem] = useState("");
  const addValue = (event) => {
    setItem(event.target.value);
  };
  const listenEnter = (event) => {
    if (event.key === "Enter" && event.target.value !== "") {
      setListItem([...itemList, item]);
      setItem("");
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        className="inputElement"
        placeholder="Enter Value"
        value={item}
        onChange={addValue}
        onKeyUp={listenEnter}
      />
      <div className="itemList">
        {itemList.map((item) => (
          <ListItem itemValue={item} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

whole code https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-meadow-h5kbxs

Comment: Thank you very much, this solution is close to what I need. Your decision deserves a bounty. The only thing, I would be very grateful to you, if you paid attention to the screenshots, you might notice the possibility for the user to delete what was written (in the screenshot this is marked with a red cross). Can you suggest me how to complete this?

Comment: Oh, I can only award a bounty after a day from its start. I will definitely do it.